# R leaflet Search Feature

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have the following shiny app: https://ahmadmobin.shinyapps.io/Understanding_STOP/

under the "Locations" tab I have a leaflet map. I want to move the search bar to the left. If possible I would like to also would like to have **addResetMapButton()** but it is not necessary.

Here is my R code:

```
output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
leaflet(Locations) %>% 
addTiles() %>% 
addCircleMarkers(color = Locations$color,clusterOptions= markerClusterOptions,
                 label=~Official_Name_of_Agency, popup=~geoAddress, group='Locations') %>% 
addLegend(labels = c("AA", "CHC", "FHT", "NPLC"), colors = c("black", "purple", "blue", "yellow")) %>% 
addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
     options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>% 
addSearchOSM(options = searchOSMOptions())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [style your apps with CSS to make custom changes to your app](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html)

For the search bar the selector you are looking for is:

```
#mymap > div.leaflet-control-container > div.leaflet-top.leaflet-right > div.leaflet-control-search.leaflet-control
```

You can use 3 different ways to change its positions (based on the link above). My prefered way is the following, especially if you are considering making more custom changes.

- In your shiny app directory create a subdirectory called `www`,

  create the style rule in a text file that moves the location of the search bar, you can figure the exact position you want but you can use something like this (this example just alters the `margin-left` attribute to shift the element to the left.

  ```
   #mymap > div.leaflet-control-container > div.leaflet-top.leaflet-right > div.leaflet-control-search.leaflet-control{margin-left: 10px important;}
  ```

  save the file as `style.css` within the `www` subdirectory,

  add a tag to your `ui.R` inside wherever you are including the render portion for your map that has:

  `tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href =   "style.css"))`

Comment: Hi eclark, thanks for getting back. Please see my response below. Have a good weekend!

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working:

style.css file #mymap > div.leaflet-control-container > div.leaflet-top.leaflet-right > div.leaflet-control-search.leaflet-control{margin-left: 10px important;}

UI:

tabItem(tabName="fourth",
                             tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href =   "style.css")),
                          leafletOutput("mymap", height=700)
                  ),

Comment: @eclark Trying to do the same thing with leaflet.extra search addSearchFeatures without succes